# Sitecore not pulling through field values

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

Instead of the field value coming through I get 'No text in the field'. This is for all views that reference a field and isn't hard coded seemingly.

The content is there in the content editor, but not pulling through to the experience editor or the live web view. I've tried rebuilding the link databases, as well as using the GUID in the view to reference the field but no luck fixing this.

For example:

Local
[image]

Experience Editor on local
[image]

Content editor on local
[image]

Live
[image]

Experience Editor on live
[image]

```html
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Data.Items
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@model RenderingModel
@{
    int counter = 0;
    int maxvisible = 6;

    // Count can be set in the control properties so the editors can vary the amount of cards showing
    if (Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.Parameters["Count"] != null)
    {
        maxvisible = int.Parse(Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.Parameters["Count"]);
    }
    var UniqueName = "";
    if (Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.Parameters["UniqueName"] != null)
    {
        UniqueName = Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.Parameters["UniqueName"];
    }
    var cardpanel = "cardpanel" + UniqueName;
    UniqueName = "expandbutton" + UniqueName;
    Item firstChild = Model.Item.Children[0];
}

<!--Adaptive code (as opposed to Responsive)-->
<!--html code for desktop version-->
<div class="container visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">

        @foreach (Item child in Model.Item.Children)
        {
            if (@Html.Sitecore().Field("ExcludeFromPage", child).ToString() != "1")
            {
                if (counter >= maxvisible)
                {
                    if (counter == maxvisible)
                    {
                        @:<div class="@cardpanel" style="display: none;">
                            @:<div class="row-eq-height">
                            }
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 CardHeightMargin flexbox">
                                <div class="rcorners1">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 img-padding cardmobile top">
                                        <div class="@Html.Sitecore().Field("{C63983F3-6ECD-45EA-A1D5-DFB37B366EDD}", child) scale-08"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 CardHeight cardmobile bottom">
                                        <h3>@Html.Sitecore().Field("{5787E6DD-A0F2-454F-AC4C-50921D4BBCB3}", child)</h3>
                                        <p>@Html.Sitecore().Field("{1E900F2F-6F68-46B4-A98A-7BDF3CE06C5E}", child)</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 CardHeightMargin flexbox">
                                <div class="rcorners1">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 img-padding cardmobile top">
                                        <div class="@Html.Sitecore().Field("{C63983F3-6ECD-45EA-A1D5-DFB37B366EDD}", child) scale-08"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 CardHeight cardmobile bottom">
                                        <h3>@Html.Sitecore().Field("{5787E6DD-A0F2-454F-AC4C-50921D4BBCB3}", child)</h3>
                                        <p>@Html.Sitecore().Field("{1E900F2F-6F68-46B4-A98A-7BDF3CE06C5E}", child)</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

        @if (counter != 0 && counter > maxvisible)
        {
        @:</div>
    @:</div>
    <div class="center-block  @UniqueName">
        <a href="#policies" class="more_link">@Html.Sitecore().Field("Expand")</a>
    </div>
}
    </div>
</div>

<!--html code for mobile version - Carousel-->
<div class="container visible-xs">
    <div id=@Model.Item.Children[0].ID.Guid.ToString("N") class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#@Model.Item.Children[0].ID.Guid.ToString("N")" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            @for (int itemcount = 1; itemcount < Model.Item.Children.Count; itemcount++)
            {
                <li data-target="#@Model.Item.Children[0].ID.Guid.ToString("N")" data-slide-to=@itemcount></li>
            }
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner m-y-1" role="listbox">
            <div class="item mobilecardheight active">
                <div class="col-xs-12 img-padding img-div-height">
                    <div class="@Html.Sitecore().Field("{C63983F3-6ECD-45EA-A1D5-DFB37B366EDD}", firstChild) scale-08"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 CardHeight ">
                    <h3>@Html.Sitecore().Field("{5787E6DD-A0F2-454F-AC4C-50921D4BBCB3}", firstChild)</h3>

                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p>@Html.Sitecore().Field("{1E900F2F-6F68-46B4-A98A-7BDF3CE06C5E}", firstChild)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            @foreach (Item child in Model.Item.Children)
            {
                if (child.ID != firstChild.ID)
                {
                    if (@Html.Sitecore().Field("ExcludeFromPage", child).ToString() != "1")
                    {
                        <div class="item mobilecardheight">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 img-padding img-div-height">
                                <div class="@Html.Sitecore().Field("{C63983F3-6ECD-45EA-A1D5-DFB37B366EDD}", child) scale-08"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 CardHeight">
                                <h3>@Html.Sitecore().Field("{5787E6DD-A0F2-454F-AC4C-50921D4BBCB3}", child)</h3>

                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <p>@Html.Sitecore().Field("{1E900F2F-6F68-46B4-A98A-7BDF3CE06C5E}", child)</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            }
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#@Model.Item.Children[0].ID.Guid.ToString("N")" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#@Model.Item.Children[0].ID.Guid.ToString("N")" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--More button javascript used on the desktop screens-->
@if (counter != 0 && counter > maxvisible)
{
    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("@UniqueName");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                var panel = this.previousElementSibling;
                if (panel != null) {
                    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                        panel.style.display = "none";
                        this.innerHTML = "<a href='#policies' class='more_link'>Show more</a>";
                    } else {
                        panel.style.display = "block";
                        this.innerHTML = "<a href='#policies' class='more_link'>Show less</a>";
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

This was all working as expected on my local, but I must've changed something elsewhere that caused this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add some more Screen shot? am not getting what content you exactly added in content editor.

Comment: Screenshots added. This was all working as expected until suddenly it dropped all the content and it won't pull any of it through anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your field references look strange to me...

- @Html.Sitecore().Field("{5787E6DD-A0F2-454F-AC4C-50921D4BBCB3}", child)

The parameters for @Html.Sitecore().Field() are:

- string FieldName
- string FieldName, Item item
- string FieldName, object parameters
- string FieldName, Item item, object parameters

Are your fields literally called "{5787E6DD-A0F2-454F-AC4C-50921D4BBCB3}" or is that just their ID? Your editor screenshot has the fields "CardText", "CardTitle", "CardIcon" and that's what I'd expect to see used instead of the GUIDs:

- @Html.Sitecore().Field("CardTitle", child)

No idea why it'd be working on live though if what you showed is also what's deployed.

Comment: It was originally the Field names, I was just trialing the IDs as a fix. Forgot to change them back. I've got this working now, it turned out to be something corrupt in the Sitecore DB which was causing the error, a new build and restoring the master DB fixed the issue.